# Ember 1.11 upgrade from 1.8

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to update an app from ember 1.8.1 to 1.11.1. When I run ember serve I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot call `compile` without the template compiler loaded. Please load `ember-template-compiler.js` prior to calling `compile`.
```

I have tried following all of these guides: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/10/16/handlebars-update.html, http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html, https://github.com/rwjblue/components-in-subdirs/commit/78e7ed2d072f42d9cf0fd3d9fc2376f106ab762e.

In particular I have definitely updated to ember-cli-htmlbars, yet I still get this error. I have tried adding this line to bower.son but with no luck:

```
"ember-template-compiler": "http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.1/ember-template-compiler.js"
```

My package.json and bower.json, and Brocfile.js are below. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

*** UPDATE ***

The problem was with ember-cli-bootstrap. Removing that fixed the issue.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mercury-ember",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for mercury-ember goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1.18",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.3",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap": "0.0.15",
    "ember-cli-cordova": "0.0.16",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.7",
    "ember-cli-font-awesome": "0.0.9",
    "ember-cli-form-data": "0.0.8",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^0.7.0",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-ion-rangeslider": "0.0.5",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.7.3",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-devise": "^0.7.3",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-testing": "0.7.3",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-uploader": "^0.3.4",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.12",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-select-2": "1.2.0",
    "emberx-slider": "1.0.3",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.0.5",
    "initials-avatar": "0.0.8",
    "liquid-fire": "^0.17.1"
  }
}
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "mercury-ember",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.11.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "ember-simple-auth": "0.7.3",
    "moment": "~2.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3",
    "ember-addons.bs_for_ember": "~0.7.0",
    "ionrangeslider": "~2.0.6",
    "select2": "~3.5.2",
    "ember-uploader": "0.3.4",
    "aws-sdk-js": "2.1.18",
    "ember-inflector": "~1.3.1"
  }
}
```

Brocfile.js:

```
/* global require, module */

var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp({
  'ember-cli-bootstrap': {
    'importBootstrapJS': true
  }
});

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding

```
"ember-template-compiler": "http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.1/ember-template-compiler.js"
```

then include it in `Brocfile.js` with adding

`app.import('bower_components/ember-template-compiler/index.js');`

before `module.exports = app.toTree();`

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this - it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Actually i think ember-cli apps don't need to include ember-template-compiler. Also make sure that all included dependencies are up to date. Are you trying to compile any template in the client? like for example: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{example}}'). I think that is causing you this error.

Comment: Thanks for this. It turned out to be a conflict with ember-cli-bootstrap. Removing that fixed the problem. The template compiler isn't required.